# Where and for how long does my referenceless javascript object exist?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

```
var SomeObj = function() {
    this.i = 0;
};

setTimeout(function() {
    new SomeObj; // I mean this object
}, 0);
```

At what point is the SomeObj object garbage collected?

Comment: after the execution of settimout's callback.

Comment: ok.. so how come I can still use the SomeObj object? suppose SomeObj references a DOM element like so: var o = this; $("#foo").click(function() {$(this).html(++o.i)});

Comment: How is that second example in your comment related to the one in the question? Of course the `o` in there does not get garbage collected because it is still being used (unlike your  `new SomeObj` in the question).

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out when the object gets garbage collected because I don't know where the object exists. The first example was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is eligible for garbage collection as soon as it is no longer used.
That means immediately after the constructor call in your case.

How timely this actually happens is an implementation detail. If you run into GC issues, you need to dig into your specific Javascript engine.

Answer (score 1):

An object that is not referenced from anywhere doesn't "exist" at all from the view of your program. How long it still resides somewhere in memory depends on the garbage collection characteristics of your interpreter, and when/whether it feels the need to collect it.

In your specific case, the object does become eligible for garbage collection right after it has been created and the reference that the expression yields is not used (e.g. in an assignment). In fact, the object might not get created at all in the first place, an optimising compiler could easily [remove the whole function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) altogether - it has no side effects and no return value.